# Transparent PNGs and Image Caching

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cache, image

We've recently started having issues where transparent PNG's are being cached with semi black backgrounds. Has anyone encountered similar issues? Some of the transparency is maintained, however some is replace by black. We're just using the below, which is pretty standard for bringing product images out onto the page;

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(100); ?>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems more logical that it's the resizing, not the caching, that causes this problem.

Comment: @rxt - More than probably, however the question remains on how we get this working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279236/how-do-i-resize-pngs-with-transparency-in-php

I see several solutions that should work. You can test them on your server, outside of magento. You could test this locally as well. This way you can see if this works at all on your server. Maybe you're missing some php module?